# How to simulate Temperature and create an office room

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1)i want to create a room from a greyscale image, i have seen two methods using gazebo:
with the tag  but with this i can't apply a texture to the side of the wall,
but only from the hight, and with the tag  but this doesn't work, and i don't undertand why,
the sdf file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

model://sun
      0 0 20
    
   
   
      model://ground_plane
    
  
      
    
      0 0 1 0 0 0
      
        
            2 2 2  
        
        
            2 2 2  
          
            1 0 0 1
            1 0 0 1

```
<!-- -->
<model name="image_map">
  <static>true</static>
  <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <link name="link">
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
    <image>
                <uri>file://media/materials/textures/room4.jpg</uri>
                <scale>20</scale>
        <threshold>200</threshold>                  
        <height>3</height>
        <granularity>1</granularity>
        </image>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <visual name="visual"> 
      <geometry>
        <image>
                <uri>file://media/materials/textures/room4.jpg</uri>
                <scale>20</scale>
        <threshold>200</threshold>                  
        <height>3</height>
        <granularity>1</granularity>
        </image> 
      </geometry>
    </visual>

  </link>
</model>
```

2. i want to simulate a physics element like the temperature in environment and to relevate it
   with a sensor, is this thing possible to do? are there any projects available?

thank you for your answer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4473/how-to-simulate-temperature-and-create-an-office-room/) by [Luigi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/477/luigi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The  geometry model is broken in Gazebo, see [this issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/847/geometry-does-not-work).

Temperature is currently no implemented in Gazebo. The easiest solution is to write a WorldPlugin that outputs temperature data. [Example world plugin](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/make_world/control). Every update cycle, your world plugin could get the position of you robot, and then output a temperature value to a topic.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GuidoG](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/553/guidog/) on 2013-10-30**:
How I can read the value published on topic?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-11-07**:
You can create a subscriber to a topic. From the command line, you can use the `gztopic -h` command.